# Executing workflow/trigger before autonumeric field is calculated

Tags: trigger, workflow, formula-field, auto-number

The scenario is:

- I have an autonumeric field `Perspective_Code__c`.
- I have a text field `Original_AC_Code__c`.
- I have an external id text field `Opportunity_Code__c`.

When a record is inserted/updated, I need to calculate `Opportunity_Code__c` depending on: if `Original_AC_Code__c` has value, Opportunity_Code__c equals to `Original_AC_Code__c` else, `Opportunity_Code__c` equals to `Perspective_Code__c`.

I cannot use a formula field to calculate `Opportunity_Code__c` because is necessary have the field as external id.

I cannot use a before trigger because, on insert, I don't have `Perspective_Code__c` value.

I cannot use an after trigger because I need to update the same record being processed.

I cannot use a workflow because, on insert, Salesforce doesn't guarantee the `Perspective_Code__c` field has value when executing.

Someone can help me how/when I can use an autonumeric field to complete another text field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a little care you can use an after trigger.

Here is a contrived example (that just sets `Account.Industry` to 'xxx'):

```
public class MyClass {
    private static Boolean executing = false;
    public static void myLogic(Account[] accounts) {
        if (!executing) {
             executing = true;
             try {
                 Account[] updates = new Account[] {};
                 for (Account a : accounts) {
                     updates.add(new Account(id = a.Id, Industry = 'xxx'));
                 }
                 update updates;
             } finally {
                 executing = false;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

and the trigger:

```
trigger MyTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {
    MyClass.myLogic(Trigger.new);
}
```

This works because:

- it isn't the list of objects from the Trigger context that are updated (as updating these would result in the error "SObjectException: DML statment cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old") but rather a separate list with the same object ids
- infinite recursion is avoided by using the static guard variable `executing` (that has to be in a separate class)

As all the required fields are available in the after trigger your logic would just be:

```
YourType__c[] updates = new YourType__c[] {};
for (YourType__c sob : sobs) {
    updates.add(new YourType__c(
            Id = sob.Id,
            Opportunity_Code__c = sob.Original_AC_Code__c != null
                    ? sob.Original_AC_Code__c
                    : sob.Perspective_Code__c
            ));
}
udpate updates;
```

Comment: Really clever. This workaround of have a new list of SObject to update in after trigger should be novel prize :)